# How to close current Extended JFrame

Tags: java, button, jframe

I have an extended JFrame, but can't use the frame.setVisible(false); to close it. I don't want to close the whole program but want to open one of my other extended JFrames in another class. How do  do that? My other class is called Genders and it must open when I press a button(btnNewGame) on my other extended JFrame.

Here is the code for my classes to open the next JFrame, but I can't close the current one:

**Class1 (the JFrame I want to close)**:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.sun.glass.events.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ProfileHome extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    ProfileHome profileHome = new ProfileHome();
                    profileHome.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ProfileHome() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        try {
             // Open an audio input stream.           
              File soundFile = new File("C:/My Awesome Stuff/Personal/Carman/My Eclipse Programs/Game/nervous_testpilot - Frozen Synapse Red - Parting Shots.flac"); //you could also get the sound file with a URL
              AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);              
             // Get a sound clip resource.
             Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
             // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
             clip.open(audioIn);
             clip.start();
          } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }


        JLabel lblWelcomeWarrior = new JLabel("Welcome, Warrior!");
        lblWelcomeWarrior.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblWelcomeWarrior.setFont(new Font("Perpetua Titling MT", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        lblWelcomeWarrior.setBounds(117, 11, 215, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblWelcomeWarrior);

        JButton btnNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
        btnNewGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Genders().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        btnNewGame.setBounds(324, 35, 100, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewGame);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\WhiteFringe\\Pictures\\Wallpapers\\9gag\\Gifs\\gixdfcbvehy.gif"));
        label.setLabelFor(label);
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
        contentPane.add(label);
    }
}
```

**Class2 (JFrame I'm opening)**:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Genders extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Genders frame = new Genders();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    /*String[] imageList = 
            {
                    "female warrior.jpg", "male warrior.jpg"
            };
    */

    public Genders() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon maleicon = new ImageIcon("male warrior.png");

        JLabel Avatar = new JLabel();
        Avatar.setBounds(0, 33, 227, 261);
        contentPane.add(Avatar);

        ImageIcon femaleicon = new ImageIcon("female warrior2.png");

        JButton btnFelame = new JButton("Female");
        btnFelame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ex) {

            Avatar.setIcon(femaleicon);
            }
        });
        btnFelame.setBounds(335, 11, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnFelame);

            JButton btnMale = new JButton("Male");
            btnMale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Avatar.setIcon(maleicon);
                }
            });
            btnMale.setBounds(335, 45, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnMale);

            JButton btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
            btnOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            });
            btnOkay.setBounds(335, 227, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnOkay);

            JLabel Genderbg = new JLabel("");
            Genderbg.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\WhiteFringe\\Pictures\\Wallpapers\\9gag\\Gifs\\llkokigiphy.gif"));
            Genderbg.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
            contentPane.add(Genderbg);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the two frames are to be part of the same program, don’t put a `public static void main()` in each. Also delete the line with `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` (or the program *will* exit when you close the frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to dispose your current class(form) and open another one, you can use the following code. In order to exit your application, use System.exit(0)

```
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            dispose();
            new Class2().setVisible(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Class2().class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

This code is to be used in the class that you want to close (e.g.Class1)

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter! You've brought my long struggle to an end. I only really needed a part of the code for it to run smoothly.

Comment: @WhiteFringe Please vote the answer and set is as the answer of your question if you are pleased.